# spring integration returning-resultset based on payload

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I'm calling procedure that returns different data in result set based on *request type*.
For this purpose I use **stored-proc-outbound-gateway**.
*Request type* is passed to procedure, but inside mapper it isn't available.

I could use ColumnMetaData to process resultSet, but I would prefer to have specific request type mappers.
Other solution is to have as many gateways as request types, but maybe there are something better.

Could I specify which mapper to use, based on payload, in **stored-proc-outbound-gateway**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, to be honest if I were you I'd really make separate components for particular types. In the future the logic might be more complex and that would be easier to modify particular function than try to figure out how to come up with all those `if..else`.

Nevertheless your request is different...

As you see there is only one possible hook for you there - `RowMapper` injection for particular procedure param.

I can suggest the solution like `RoutingRowMapper`, which will consult some `ThreadLocal` variable to select the proper `RowMapper` to delegate.

The idea is picked up from the `AbstractRoutingDataSource`. Also there is something like `SimpleRoutingConnectionFactory` in the Spring AMQP.

The `ThreadLocal` you can populate before `stored-proc-outbound-gateway` and that really can be your desired type.

Another trick might be based on the result from the procedure where `ResultSet` contains a column with a hint which target `RowMapper` to choose.

In any way your task can be achieved only via composite `RowMapper`. The `stored-proc-outbound-gateway` doesn't have any logic to tackle and won't. It's just not its responsibility.

Comment: Thank you for clarification. 
I have made separate request type processors.
I agree, it is much cleaner solution that making decision inside RowMapper.